# Rails respond_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My question is probably simple: 
On my page you can activate a modal (bootstrap) by clicking on a link. That modal contains a form. So if someone submit that form, and some input fields are not valid, I want to reload the page, load this modal automatically this time, showing the the form including the error-messages.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to reload the page. Will it not be ok if u will be redirected to form if it contains invalid inputs with error messages via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

you can have a remote form that interacts with a controller on the server side just as normal:

```
<%= form_tag('/example_path', remote: true) %>
```

The `remote: true` part tells the javascript Rails ships with (if you have included it that is) to perform an ajax request, instead of a normal request. Yo can treat it like a normal request on the server side:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def method
    # [...]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :template }
    end
  end
end
```

The difference here is that you use `format.js` instead of the usual `format.html`. Rails will look for a different template extension (in this example the file would be called `tempalte.js`. You can treat it as a normal template file and use Ruby and JS in it. Rails will evaluate the request when the response from the server returns.

For more info, have a a look [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) or [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript).